# Evaluation of cout if it has a constexpr value?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

class dummy{
public:
    constexpr
        dummy(int one, int two) noexcept
        :x(one),y(two){
    }


    constexpr int getX() noexcept{
        return x;
    }

    constexpr int gety() noexcept{
        return y;
    }

    constexpr int operator+(const dummy& asd){
        return (this->getX() + asd.getX() + this->gety() + asd.gety()) ;
    }

private:
    int x;
    int y;
};


int main(){
    constexpr dummy d1(2,4);
    constexpr dummy d2(2,4);

    int rand = 10;
    std::cout<<d1+d2<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

From my understanding, a function can be evaluated at compile time if it's declared as `constexpr` and it if took `constexpr` values.

Questions:

From this line, `std::cout<<d1+d2<<std::endl;` since `d1 + d2` is a constexpr and cout operator is not. is `d1+d2` going to be evaluated at compile time? what will happen to the `cout` around it? I'm concerned about what's happening inside.

Comment: Basically, the outcome is equivalent to `std::cout << 12 << std::endl;` The value of `d1+d2` may be computed at compile time, but of course characters `'1'` and `'2'` can only written to the standard output at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`constexpr`'s are evaluated in compile time, not in run time as you have mentioned in question.

So in your example following statements are evaluated in compile time and initilize d1 and d2 .

```
constexpr dummy d1(2,4);
constexpr dummy d2(2,4);
```

And in compile time , it will do summation of `d1` an `d2`   using `constexpr` of operator overloaded function for summation

So in run time following statement   print the result  of expression `d1+d2` that was already computed during compile time.

```
std::cout<<d1+d2<<std::endl;
```

Comment: So it's like, `cout` will just wait at run time?